# How to pass a value from an onChange event to a Django url template?

Tags: django, geodjango

It seems like what I would like to do should be a simple thing, but I haven't been able to figure it out. I'm using Django 2.06 with Geodjango. I have a simple UI with a dropdown menu. In order to respond to changes in dropdown selections, I have an event listener for onChange events. The idea is to get the e.target.value from the event and make it the value of a query parameter in a URL.

So in index.html I have:

```
const property_name = document.getElementsByName('properties')[0];
property_name.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
zones = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("{% url 'zones' property=e.target.value %}", { ...
```

In urls.py I have:

```
url(r'^zones_data/$', zone_datasets2, name='zones'),
```

and in views.py I have:

```
def zone_datasets2(request):
    property = request.GET.get('property', '')
```

When I try to load my webpage, the error I get is:

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'zones' with keyword arguments '{'property': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:          ['zones_data/$']
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? How can I pass the dropdown menu selection to the URL and how can I define a url pattern that works with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have urls like `/zones_data?property=...`, you should have:

```
"{% url 'zones' %}?property=e.target.value"
```

Comment: Okay, that got rid of the error, thank you. But my property isn't making it to my views. 
    property = request.GET.get('property', '') doesn't give me the e.target.value value. I get no value back from this call.

Comment: Oh, I figured out my problem. Should have had:  L.GeoJSON.AJAX("{% url 'zones' %}?property="+e.target.value,...

Comment: That's it :) You can suggest an edit to the answer with the working version of the code. By the way, there is also another (possibly _better_ if your `property` in a fixed format) way of doing what you want; you can include `kwarg` in your url and use that in your script.